# Is there a way to use another languages for scripting on blender?

Tags: python, scripting, customization

I don't have anything against Python and think it is an awesome language. But I, personally, am used to be much more productive with functional languages in general. Thinks like `map`, `fold` and first class lambdas help me a lot when programming. Python's support for FP, while acceptable, is far from ideal. With this, I ask: is there any way to use another language for blender scripting? Something with a Haskell-like syntax would be great, but even JavaScript/CoffeeScript/Etc would help me a lot already.

Comment: The answer you are looking for is no.

Comment: I don't think the "duplicate" question really addresses the same scope as this, but in it ideasMan42 suggested this possibility, "You can also use languages which are supported as Python extensions - So you can for example use a lisp variant called hy."

Comment: He doesn't explain how that could be possible, though.